# Help calculating the following Integral?

Tags: integration

How can I calculate this? $\int_{0}^2 f(x)$  $\mathrm{dx}$ if $$f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x, & 0 \le x <1 \\
x-2 & 1 \le x \le 2
\end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**
The integral you're working with is equivalent to $$\int_0^1 x\ dx +\int_1^2 (x-2)\ dx.$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I was wondering if I could do that since one of the intervals is $[0, 1)$.

Comment: That's a good observation. If the other interval were $(1,2]$, then the function would be undefined at $x=1$ and we'd have a problem. But notice that since the second interval is $[1,2]$, $f(x)$ is actually defined at every $x$-value in the interval, so you can go ahead and split the integral.

Comment: No problem; happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

$$\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^{2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int\limits_{0}^{1}f(x)\mathrm{d}x + \int\limits_{1}^{2}f(x)\mathrm{d}x$$